# Javascript working in local but not on a server

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been working on a page which has 3 input fields and 3 buttons. The input fields are Date, Territory, and Town while the buttons are Save, Back, and Add.
The Save and add buttons are disabled until the user enter values in the 3 input fields. When the user inputs a value in the date and town field a table will appear. While the territory field filters the contents/options in the town field. The problem is the javascript doesnt work when placed on a server.

Here are the HTML codes with inline Javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">

    <link rel="icon" href="../images/logo.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/allStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/runnable.css" />
    <script src="../js/datepick.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/datepick1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    //DISABLING SAVE AND ADD WHEN INPUT FIELDS ARE EMPTY
    $(function(){
            //Set button disabled
            $("#subAdd").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            $("#subSv").attr("disabled", "disabled");

            //Append a change event listener to input
            $("input[name='txtDay']").change(function(){

                if($(this).val().length > 0) {
                    $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");  
                }                            
            });

            $("input[name='terlist']").change(function(){

                if($(this).val().length > 0) {
                    $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");  
                }                            
            });

            $("input[name='town-list']").change(function(){

                if($(this).val().length > 0) {
                    $("input[type='submit']").removeAttr("disabled");  
                }                            
            });

            //trigger the a change event
            $("input[name='txtDay'], input[name='town-list'], input[name='terlist']").trigger('change');
    });
    </script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    //GETTING SAVED MCP RECORDS DATABASE
    function getData(val){
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mcp_getdate.php",
            data:'target_date='+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#list-added").html(data);
                document.getElementById("town-list").onchange();
            }
            });
    }
    </script>

    <script type ="text/javascript">
    //GETTING TERRITORIES IN DATABASE  
    function getTown(val){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "mcp_gettown.php",
        data:'territory_id='+val,
        success: function(data){
            $("#town-list").html(data);
        }
        });
    }
    </script>

    <script  type ="text/javascript">
    //GETTING DATABASE VALUES FOR ADD
    function submitForm() {
            var myDate = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
            var myFrame =  document.getElementById("mcpFrame");
            var myCheckboxes = new Array();
            $("input:checked").each(function() {
               myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "mcp_set.php",
                dataType: 'html',
                data: 'search_value='+myCheckboxes+'&date_value='+myDate+'&mcpFrame'+myFrame,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#list-added").html(data);
                    document.getElementById("town-list").value = "";
                    document.getElementById("town-list").onchange();
                }
            });
            return false;

    }
    </script>

    <script  type ="text/javascript">
    // SETTING CHECKBOXES
    function getSchool(val){
            var myDate = document.getElementById("datepicker").value;
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "mcp_settown.php",
            data:'town_id='+val+'&target_date='+myDate,
            success: function(data){
                $("#school-list").html(data);
            }
            });
    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

        <!--HEADER-->

        <table class="table tableser">
            <tr>
                <td class="tableser" width="50%"></td>
                <?php
                    if(empty($_SESSION["user_id"])) {
                        header('Location: ../login/index.php');
                        exit(); 
                    }
                    else{
                        if($_SESSION["dept_id"] == 2 ) {
                ?>
                <td class="tableser" align="right" style="vertical-align:bottom" width="50%"><b><?php  echo "NAME : " . $_SESSION["emp_name"]; ?></b></td>
                <?php
                        }                       
                        if($_SESSION["dept_id"] != 2 ) {
                        session_unset(); 

                        // destroy the session 
                        session_destroy(); 
                        header('Location: ../login/index.php');
                        exit();
                        }
                    }
                ?>
                <td class="tableser" width="4%" style="vertical-align:bottom" align="right"><b><a href="../logout/index.php">(LOGOUT)</a></b></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <hr>

        <!--Save and Back -->

        <table class="tableser">
                <tr>
                    <td  class="tableser" width="90%"><b>Monthly Call Plan Entry</b></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableser">
                        <form method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                          <input type="submit" id="subSv" name="subSv" value="Save" style="height:25px; width:80px; font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger"/>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="tableser" align = "right">   
                        <form method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
                            <input type="submit" name="subHd" value="Back" style="height:25px; width:80px; font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger"/>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </table>    
        <hr>

        <!--CONTENT-->

        <form method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm" action="">
            <table  class="tableser">
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableser">Date</td>
                    <td class="tableser">
                        <input type="text" name="txtDay" id="datepicker" placeholder="Enter date." size="35px" onChange="getData(this.value);" required />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableser">Territory</td>
                    <td class="tableser">
                        <select name="terlist" id="terr-list"  style="height:25px; width:279px; font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger"  onChange="getTown(this.value);">
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Territory..</option>
                            <?php
                                $sqlTer = "SELECT DISTINCT tbl_all.territory_id, tbl_all.user_id , tbl_territory.province FROM tbl_all 
                                                    JOIN tbl_territory ON tbl_all.territory_id = tbl_territory.territory_id
                                                    WHERE user_id = ".$_SESSION["user_id"]." ";
                                $result_sqlTer = $conn->query($sqlTer);
                                 while($row = $result_sqlTer->fetch_assoc())
                                 {
                                ?>
                                     <option value="<?php echo $row["territory_id"]; ?>"><?php echo $row["province"]; ?></option>
                                <?php
                                 }
                                ?>              
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="tableser">Town</td>
                    <td class="tableser">
                        <select name="townlist" id="town-list"  style="height:25px; width:279px; font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger" onChange="getSchool(this.value);" >
                            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Town..</option>
                        </select> 
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <br>

        <div id="school-list" style="overflow-y: auto;" >
        </div>


        <br>
        <input type="submit" id="subAdd" name="subAdd" value="Add"  onclick="return submitForm()" style="height:25px; width:80px; font-face: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: larger" />
        <br>
        </form>

        <br>
        <div id= "list-added" style="overflow-y: auto;">
        </div>
        <center>
        <iframe id="mcpFrame" name="mcpFrame" style="visibility:hidden;display:none"></iframe>
        </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: any error on console

Comment: You are not including jQuery anywhere, is it part of one of the other scripts?

Comment: Just to be clear, a server sends html/javascript to a client (usually a browser) which then renders your page and runs your javascript code.  Is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: session probably hasn't been started; unknown.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't even get that far... And php `header()` redirects in the middle of the page, same problem.

Comment: @jeroen I went through his code *real fast like* ;-)

Comment: well I'm outta here. *ciao tutti*

Comment: @CodeLove the error on the console are 500 Internal Server Error, and 404 Not Found on the date picker, which is kinda wierd since the only one that works when on a server is the date picker.

Comment: @jeroen Have jquery-1.11.3 and jquery-1.7 on the server, and tried both of them. Still didn't work. Kinda weird though since the code runs without jquery on local. I just copied the syntax from different parts of the program.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just didn't include the php since its just setting the session the the back and save button which is redirect and insert.

Answer (score 0):

Please include jquery-[version].js in your page, I see it's missing. Hopefully you didn't rename jquery-[version].js to script.js.

Comment: I have jquery-1.11.3 but i didn't include it in the scripts since it still works on local without it.